# find the population density of some points in qgis/postgis

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, density, population

I have the tiger census data of population density in each block group. I also have a different kind of data: traffic accident data, where an accident has a lat/lon pair. My goal is to find the population density of each accident location.

How can I match the accident to the block groups?

[image: population density map]

[image: crash location map]

Comment: so you're just trying to get the population value from each block group that each accident point intersects?

Comment: Yes. <accident1,population1> <accident2,population2>.

Comment: Don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31251017/327026)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) function, and use a query like this:

```
    select 
acc.[column]
    , bg.[population]
      from accidents as acc
    join blockgroups as bg on ST_Intersects(acc.geom, bg.geom)
```

Comment: Thank you, I am sure this is the right way to do. But I didn't see a geometry column in the population data. Is there any way to add it?

Comment: is it called SHAPE or something? If you're running PGAdmin you should be able to inspect the table and the columns to see which one is the geometry...

Comment: Thank you Baker! I found it in PGAdmin. Interesting Qgis didn't show the geom.

Comment: @daydayup if you use the DB Manager tool, it will show you the properties of your PostGIS tables, and list the fields and data types of the columns of your tables. That might be the best place to interact with your PostGIS database in QGIS...